# macro rule only matches first pattern

Tags: macros, rust

I wrote a macro for sym-linking files. At first I had just the first pattern, but then thought that it would be nice not to have to write "&format!" all the time.

So with these patterns:

```
macro_rules! syml {
    ($a:expr, $b:expr) => {
        Command::new("ln").args(&["-s", $a, $b])
    };
    ( ($a:expr, $($x:expr),+), ($b:expr, $($y:expr),+) ) => {
        Command::new("ln").args(&["-s", &format!($a, $($x),+), &format!($b, $($y),+)])
    }
}
```

I want to match these cases:

```
syml!("from", "to");
syml!(("{}", from), "to");
syml!("from", ("{}", to));
syml!(("{}", from), ("{}", to));
syml!(("{}{}", from, here), ("{}{}", to, there));
```

But so far every time only the first pattern is matched, so I'm getting `mismatched types` errors like `expected reference, found tuple`.

I don't understand why, even for the last two example cases, it tries to match the first pattern and not the second.

Comment: Not a macro specialist, so I'll just make 2 quick points: (1) a tuple is an expression, so "(x, y)" can match `$a:expr` and (2) I believe the patterns are tried in order... have you tried putting the more specific pattern first?

Comment: Not related to the problem, but the standard library has a [`symlink`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/os/unix/fs/fn.symlink.html) function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @MatthieuM points out in a comment, a tuple is an expression and macro rules are tried in order.

So in your case:

```
macro_rules! syml {
    ($a:expr, $b:expr) => {
        Command::new("ln").args(&["-s", $a, $b])
    };
    ( ($a:expr, $($x:expr),+), ($b:expr, $($y:expr),+) ) => {
        Command::new("ln").args(&["-s", &format!($a, $($x),+), &format!($b, $($y),+)])
    }
}
```

The first rule will always match any time the second would.  The solution is to swap them around:

```
macro_rules! syml {
    ( ($a:expr, $($x:expr),+), ($b:expr, $($y:expr),+) ) => {
        Command::new("ln").args(&["-s", &format!($a, $($x),+), &format!($b, $($y),+)])
    };
    ($a:expr, $b:expr) => {
        Command::new("ln").args(&["-s", $a, $b])
    }
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=dbc25ae8a1431a552d6afd8c4ee8f28e&version=stable&backtrace=1))

The above doesn't cover two of your test cases where you mix tuples and strings:

```
syml!(("{}", from), "to");
syml!("from", ("{}", to));
```

This can be simply fixed by adding new cases (in order).  (I don't know if it's possible to factor out the tuple/string matching, but would be interested in seeing any solutions.)

```
macro_rules! syml {
    ( ($a:expr, $($x:expr),+), ($b:expr, $($y:expr),+) ) => {
        Command::new("ln").args(&["-s", &format!($a, $($x),+), &format!($b, $($y),+)])
    };
    ( $a:expr, ($b:expr, $($y:expr),+) ) => {
        Command::new("ln").args(&["-s", $a, &format!($b, $($y),+)])
    };
    ( ($a:expr, $($x:expr),+), $b:expr ) => {
        Command::new("ln").args(&["-s", &format!($a, $($x),+), $b])
    };
    ($a:expr, $b:expr) => {
        Command::new("ln").args(&["-s", $a, $b])
    }
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=44cf7ab7240fdcab3fabcaf32f3a3a3e&version=stable&backtrace=1))

Comment: Of course a tuple is an expression! I totally missed that, thanks. Also thanks to @MatthieuM.

Comment: And thanks for the edit and providing the fix for my two uncovered test cases! A solution with less rules would indeed be interesting. Maybe I can find one after digging more into rust macros.

Comment: Nice to see my hunch was right; I really haven't played much with macros :)